Using `pg_restore` after `pg_dump`
I'm trying to move from SQL Server to Postgres and am trying to check that I can restore a backup.
The first boobytrap is that the pg_dump command for backup must be done with the -F custom option in order to be usable with pg_restore.
# pg_dump -U postgres -h localhost -F custom TheDatbase | 7z -si -mx=9 a "/root/TheDatbase.pg_dump.7z"

The second boobytrap is that you can't get the output of the 7z extraction directly into pg_restore; you have to extract it to a disc file.
# 7z x -so TheDatbase.pg_dump.7z | pg_restore -U postgres -h localhost -C -d TheDatbaseR

ERROR: No more files
TheDatbase



System ERROR:
Unknown error -2147024872
pg_restore: error: input file is too short (read 0, expected 5)

# 7z x -so TheDatbase .pg_dump.7z > pg_restore -U postgres -h localhost -C -d TheDatbaseR


Command Line Error:
Too short switch:
-U

# 7z x -so TheDatbase .pg_dump.7z | pg_restore -U postgres -h localhost -C -d EquitiesR -f -

ERROR: No more files
TheDatbase



System ERROR:
Unknown error -2147024872
pg_restore: error: options -d/--dbname and -f/--file cannot be used together
pg_restore: hint: Try "pg_restore --help" for more information.

# 7z x -so TheDatbase .pg_dump.7z > TheDatbase .pg_dump

(But pg_restore --help says nothing about using the -d and -f flags together.)
Finally, pg_restore is broken because -C is supposed to create the database.
# pg_restore -U postgres -h localhost -C -d TheDatbaseR TheDatbase.pg_dump
Password:
pg_restore: error: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  database "TheDatbaseR" does not exist
#

This also all only works as the postgres user.
What are the usual workarounds to get this to work?
Is Postgres really this broken? (I guess that's free stuff for you?)
